# Migrate .xproj to .csproj in vs 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a .xproj project which I want to migrate to .csproj. When I try to open it in vs 2017, I get this message:-

[image]

And once I press OK on that message, I get this error:-

[image]

I dont know where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try contacting Microsoft Support?

Comment: Is there an error message in your Windows Event Log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to migrate my .xproj to .csproj with the following steps:-

in `cmd` navigate to the directory where your .xproj is present and run `dotnet migrate`, however `dotnet migrate` is not compatible with the newer versions of .net core sdk.

To check which sdks you have installed run: `dotnet --list-sdks`

Then from the sdks you have installed, switch to an sdk which has support for the `dotnet migrate` command or install an sdk with support for the command. In my case I didnt have any sdks installed with support for this command so I installed `2.0.2`

Then I navigated to the directory where .xproj was present and ran: `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.0.2` to switch to this version of `dotnet` and after that I was finally able to run `dotnet migrate` which worked as expected.